# Using VBA .NumberFormat is there a way to format an entire column as a Zip Code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to format an entire column as a zip code with VBA. I know this can be done by selecting Special --> Zip Code from the numbers drop down. Is this something that the .NumberFormat function supports in VBA?

I tried this with no luck:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).NumberFormat = "Zip Code"
```

Comment: USA zipcodes only? in Canada, they are in `A1A 1A1` format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro recorder is pretty helpful here:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).NumberFormat = "00000"
```

<sup>*</sup> This format is applicable to US (and some other) zip codes, which have 5 digits and can contain leading zeros.

Comment: USA zipcodes only? in Canada, they are in `A1A 1A1` format...

Comment: @braX that is a good point. Although I'm guessing OP is USA from the "Boston" portion.

Comment: @braX - I was also thinking about it. In Germany they are also with 5 digits. Can someone from Netherlands with a Dutch Excel give it a try? They have letters there.

Comment: but the OP could be using a spreadsheet that has some Canadian locations mixed in (The place I worked at had that happen all the time)

Comment: @braX well if they are in the form A1A 1A1 they will not be affected - they will display as text. Come to think of it, how would there be a special format for a Canadian zip code? It will just be text, right?

Comment: Why not only `"0"`? - In order to take countries like Austria into account, which only have 4-digit ZIP codes, a reduced number format, such as ("0000" or even) "0" should suffice if it can be assumed that the ZIP lengths are uniform for each country and don't start with a zero digit.

Comment: @T.M. - the assumption that they don't start with a zero doesn't not apply to the US.

Comment: Thx for hint; so countries with less digits than five  will have leading zeros applying "00000" as NumberFormat. @BigBen

Answer (score 1):

This is what the macro recorder produces:

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'

'
    Range("E4").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "00000"
End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen - true. And you even had some time to format the code a bit better:)

Comment: Haha :) I still think two answers that nudge OP to use the macro recorder are a good "hint hint, you can figure this out" :)

Answer (score -1):

I had forgotten about using macro recorder and found this through my own searching.

This is what the current macro record produces:

```
Columns("AD:AD").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "00000"
```

The original answer did not work for me.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).NumberFormat = "00000"
```

Comment: Try `Columns("AD:AD").NumberFormat = "00000"`. There is [no need to Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).